# Searching pdfs in a C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, solr, ghostscript

I need to create a winform in Visual Studio 2010 using C# that searches a directory for pdf files and then searches for certain text within the pdfs.  For example, the user may enter "John Smith" into the winform.  The program needs to search all the pdfs in a given directory for the text "John Smith."  I currently do not have Adobe Acrobat and likely will not be able to purchase it or any non-free add-ins.  I've been told to look at Apache Solr and Ghostscript, but don't see how those could be used in a winform.  I've search for this a lot and seen lots of suggestions, but can't find any simple examples or tutorials on how to set up a winform to search pdfs.  Can someone provide me with some sample code on how to search pdfs in a winform?

Comment: I've downloaded solr and ghostscript, but don't know how to set them up or use them within my visual studio project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search certian text in PDF you can use the ITextSharp library at 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Here is a quick example

```
var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath); 
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();  

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) 
    output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

//now you can search for the text from outPut.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea how to do the same thing with Ghostscript?  Also, what would I need to include to use itextsharp (such as putting using #itextsharp at the top or copying .dlls to a certain folder)?

Comment: Ghostscript is built as a DLL on Windows and since it is supplied as source can obviously be rebuilt as a static library or other component. I know nothing about Winform but I can't see why this should be an insuperable obstacle. Text can be extracted using the 'txtwrite' device. I would say that GS is probably too much of a sledgehammer for your purposes, you might like to consider MuPDF, if you only want to handle PDF files.

Comment: I used the test script from http://www.wibit.net/blog/integrating_ghostscript_c to convert a pdf to a ps file, which works.  I tried changing it to a text file (using txtwrite), but the output file was blank.  Even if those worked, I still don't know how to search the new ps or text file from C#.  Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Here's the code I tried that doesn't work (produces a blank txt file):
        WiBit.Net.WGhostScript gs = new WiBit.Net.WGhostScript();
        gs.AddParam("-q");
        gs.AddParam("-dNOPAUSE");
        gs.AddParam("-dBATCH");
        gs.AddParam("-dQUIET");
        gs.AddParam("-sDEVICE=txtwrite");
        gs.AddParam("-dLanguageLevel=" + psLanguageLevel.ToString());
        gs.AddParam("-dSetPageSize");
        gs.AddParam("-sOutputFile=" + psFilePath);
        gs.AddParam(pdfFilePath);
        gs.Execute();

Comment: Looks like iTextSharp is the only answer.  Thanks!